# Lenovo ThinkPad USB-C Dock Gen 2 works with ThinkPad T440 to project the displays?

Tags: thinkpad, usb-c, dock

I have a [Lenovo ThinkPad USB-C Dock Gen 2](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/accessories-and-monitors/docking/universal-cable-docks-usb/TP-USB-C-DOCK-GEN2-US/p/40AS0090US) that works well with my [ThinkPad 480](https://www.lenovo.com/ph/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-t-series/ThinkPad-T480/p/22TP2TT4800) to connect my dual monitors. I have another Lenovo PC, [ThinkPad T440](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/t-series/t440/) and want to connect this to my Dock as well. However, my T440 doesn't have a USB Type-C Port, but it has a Mini DisplayPort.

I purchased a [Mini DisplayPort to USB-C cord](https://www.lazada.com.ph//products/i1283288163-s4653656907.html?spm=a2o4l.cart.0.0.2eb33e17VzxDEl&urlFlag=true) to connect the T440 to the Dock but it didn't work. Will a MiniDP to HDMI work instead? No power delivery is fine. I just want to be able to project the displays.

Thanks!

Comment: Seriously doubt it. Might actually be a better question for Lenovo themselves since you are looking to use three Lenovo products to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The cable you have is directional, it takes input on USB-C and sends output on mini-DP.  At least that's how it appears from the product description.  Getting multiple displays from one DP port means using MST, multiple stream transport, and if your ThinkPad T440 does not support this then even with the correct cable will not grant the ability to drive two displays from the single port.

I have seen adapters that will take two USB 3.0 ports and a DP port as input and provide a USB-C port for connecting a dock like this.  These violate the USB spec so personally I would not touch them unless I was in very dire need.  I have no idea how much they cost or where to get them, I merely saw a mention of such an adapter on a YouTube demonstration of VR goggles and displays that use USB-C.

It sounds like you may need another dock, or just swap cables as needed.  Perhaps a KVM switch is what you are looking for.  I will say that finding the right adapters could cost more time and money than just buying the right dock.  Getting the wrong cable, like one that violates the USB spec, could cost you that dock by damaging something.